# How to sort a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have following type of list

```
lst = [
    [1, 0.23],
    [2, 0.39],
    [4, 0.31],
    [5, 0.27],
]
```

I want to sort this in descending order of the second column. I tried built-in `sorted()` function in python, but it gives me `'TypeError' : 'float' object is unsubscriptable`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not a list. That is a sequence of numbers with newlines, but not any Python structure. Please post the actual code that failed for you, and the representation of the list.

Comment: Now we have a sequence of python lists; is there an outer list?

Comment: Clearly not off-topic, since it's the #1 Google search result for sorting a 2D list in Python, and the best answer has 15 up-votes.

Comment: Agreed. If StackOverflow explains why this is off-topic, we could improve it. It is a typical question to ask how to do a non-trivial task in Python, and the task has multiple approaches as shown below.

Answer (score 70):

You can use a lambda:

```
>>> li=[[1, 0.23],
... [2, 0.39],
... [4, 0.31],
... [5, 0.27]]
>>> sorted(li,key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=True)
[[2, 0.39], [4, 0.31], [5, 0.27], [1, 0.23]]
```

Or the other way:

```
>>> sorted(li,key=lambda l:l[1])
[[1, 0.23], [5, 0.27], [4, 0.31], [2, 0.39]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works a treat, but mind explaining what 'l:l[1]' do?

Comment: A lambda is a small anonymous function in Python. The `l` is the argument to the lambda separated by the body of the function by `:`. The `l[1]` takes the list passed to the lambda and returns the second item (subscript `[1]` is the second item...)

Answer (score 23):

To sort a list of lists on the second column, use [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for ease and clarity:

```
from operator import itemgetter
outputlist = sorted(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

or, to sort in-place:

```
from operator import itemgetter
inputlist.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

`itemgetter()` is a little faster than using a `lambda` for the task.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> inputlist = [
...     [1, 0.23],
...     [2, 0.39],
...     [4, 0.31],
...     [5, 0.27],
... ]
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[[2, 0.39], [4, 0.31], [5, 0.27], [1, 0.23]]
```

You'd only see your exception if you had floating point values *in your inputlist directly*:

```
>>> inputlist.append(4.2)
>>> inputlist
[[1, 0.23], [2, 0.39], [4, 0.31], [5, 0.27], 4.2]
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

(for Python 3; Python 2's error message is slightly different, resulting in `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` instead).

This is because the `itergetter(1)` call is applied to all elements in the outer list but only works on nested ordered sequences, not on the one floating point value now added.

Comment: I tried this, but since my second column is float it gives me 'TypeError' : 'float' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: @ChinthakaNadunRatnaweera: No, then your list is not nested. You have float values *directly* referenced in your outer list. Print your list and copy it to your question.