# Python string data sort

Tags: python

I have my AWS Python lambda function return the string with below data:

```
mydata = ( 
#user                            #Key                           #age

eks-user            AKIAII4CCN6AA           288  days
eks-user            AKIAJFUU2ASII           100  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           847  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAIAWETFUK            134  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAI7OTKONT            199  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAICIDXLDU            100  days
text@abc.com                    AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           120      days )
```

which I want to sort by age.

Please let me know the recommendations which works here?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to use the sort and sorted method which doesn't help.

```
mydata.sort(key=AgeSort)
print(f'list of Compliance Users: {username}')

#Sort the user by age
def AgeSort(d):
    return d[str(age)]
```

I expect the output:

```
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           847  days
eks-user            AKIAII4CCN6AA           288  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAI7OTKONT            199  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAIAWETFUK            134  days
text@abc.com        AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           120  days
eks-user            AKIAJFUU2ASII           100  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAICIDXLDU            100  days
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563680/sorting-2d-list-python?

Comment: What type of object is `mydata`? Is it a list? A string? How did you print it like that?

Comment: it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

aws_string = """eks-user            AKIAII4CCN6AA           288  days
eks-user            AKIAJFUU2ASII           100  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           847  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAIAWETFUK            134  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAI7OTKONT            199  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAICIDXLDU            100  days
text@abc.com                    AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           120      days"""

def sort_string(string):
    string = string.split("\n")
    array_of_data = []
    for line in string:
        array_of_data.append(line.split())
    #array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data,key=lambda l:l[2], reverse=True)
    array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
    return array_of_data

ls = sort_string(aws_string)
for l in ls:
    print(l)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
['Oracle_RMAN', 'AKIAJ4DMBBCEP', '847', 'days']
['eks-user', 'AKIAII4CCN6AA', '288', 'days']
['nb-dev-api', 'AKIAI7OTKONT', '199', 'days']
['Oracle_RMAN', 'AKIAIAWETFUK', '134', 'days']
['text@abc.com', 'AKIAJ4DMBBCEP', '120', 'days']
['eks-user', 'AKIAJFUU2ASII', '100', 'days']
['nb-dev-api', 'AKIAICIDXLDU', '100', 'days']
```

#### Return a string

```
from operator import itemgetter

aws_string = """eks-user            AKIAII4CCN6AA           288  days
eks-user            AKIAJFUU2ASII           100  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           847  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAIAWETFUK            134  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAI7OTKONT            199  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAICIDXLDU            100  days
text@abc.com                    AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           120      days"""

def sort_string(string):
    string = string.split("\n")
    array_of_data = []
    for line in string:
        array_of_data.append(line.split())
    #array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data,key=lambda l:l[2], reverse=True)
    array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

    for l in array_of_data:
        array_of_data[array_of_data.index(l)] = " ".join(l)

    array_of_data = "\n".join(array_of_data)
    return array_of_data

ls = sort_string(aws_string)
print(ls)
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Oracle_RMAN AKIAJ4DMBBCEP 847 days
eks-user AKIAII4CCN6AA 288 days
nb-dev-api AKIAI7OTKONT 199 days
Oracle_RMAN AKIAIAWETFUK 134 days
text@abc.com AKIAJ4DMBBCEP 120 days
eks-user AKIAJFUU2ASII 100 days
nb-dev-api AKIAICIDXLDU 100 days
```

#### This should works

```
from operator import itemgetter

aws_string = """eks-user            AKIAII4CCN6AA           288  days
eks-user            AKIAJFUU2ASII           100  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           847  days
Oracle_RMAN         AKIAIAWETFUK            134  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAI7OTKONT            199  days
nb-dev-api          AKIAICIDXLDU            100  days
text@abc.com                    AKIAJ4DMBBCEP           120      days"""


def sort_string(string):
    string = string.split("\n")
    array_of_data = []
    for line in string:
        array_of_data.append(line.split())
    #array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data,key=lambda l:l[2], reverse=True)
    array_of_data = sorted(array_of_data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

    for l in array_of_data:
        array_of_data[array_of_data.index(l)] = " ".join(l)

    array_of_data = "\n".join(array_of_data)
    return array_of_data
complianceusers = sort_string(aws_string)
print(complianceusers)
```

### output

> ```
> Oracle_RMAN AKIAJ4DMBBCEP 847 days
> eks-user AKIAII4CCN6AA 288 days
> nb-dev-api AKIAI7OTKONT 199 days
> Oracle_RMAN AKIAIAWETFUK 134 days
> text@abc.com AKIAJ4DMBBCEP 120 days
> eks-user AKIAJFUU2ASII 100 days
> nb-dev-api AKIAICIDXLDU 100 days
> ```

Comment: Thank you, Gianni, for your quick response.

Comment: I got an error: Response:
`{
  "errorMessage": "list index out of range",
  "errorType": "IndexError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      90,
      "lambda_handler",
      "complianceusers = SortUsers(username)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      115,
      "SortUsers",
      "arry_of_data = sorted(arry_of_data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)"
    ]
  ]
}`

Comment: here is my code: `  complianceusers = SortUsers(username)  
        print(complianceusers)  def SortUsers(username):  
    string = username.split('\n')  
    arry_of_data = []  
    
    for line in string:  
        arry_of_data.append(line.split())  
    arry_of_data = sorted(arry_of_data, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)  
    
    '''for l in arry_of_data:  
        arry_of_data[arry_of_data.index(1)] = " ".join(1)  
        
    arry_of_data = '\n'.join(arry_of_data)'''  
    return arry_of_data`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution specific to your question

```
arr = [l.split() for l in aws_string.split('\n')]
arr.sort(key=lambda l:int(l[2]), reverse=True)
s = '\n'.join('\t'.join(a) for a in arr)
print(s)
```

This will produce the following output

```
Oracle_RMAN     AKIAJ4DMBBCEP       847     days
eks-user        AKIAII4CCN6AA       288     days
nb-dev-api      AKIAI7OTKONT        199     days
Oracle_RMAN     AKIAIAWETFUK        134     days
text@abc.com    AKIAJ4DMBBCEP       120     days
eks-user        AKIAJFUU2ASII       100     days
nb-dev-api      AKIAICIDXLDU        100     days
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply.  I got a syntax error.  `    87   arr = [l.split() for l in username.split('\n')]
    88   arr.sort(key=lamda l:int(1[2]), reverse=True)
    89    s = '\n'.join('\t'.join(a) for a in arr)
    90   print(s) ` error message:  _
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"
}

Request ID:
"9b2d698b-665d-4782-ae67-37b8b6c9cb67"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 9b2d698b-665d-4782-ae67-37b8b6c9cb67 Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 88)
_

Comment: You wrote `lamda` instead of `lambda`. And it is `int(l[2])` not `int(1[2])`